# How do I change the default gemset and ruby version for my project?

Tags: ruby, rvm

When I list all the versions of Ruby on my system, I get this:

```
$ rvm list rubies

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p370 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

When I list the gemset in a new Terminal window for my project, I see this:

```
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p392 (found in /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392)
   (default)
=> myapp
   boso
   global
```

So, I change the version of `1.9.3` that I want to use:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194
Using /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
=> (default)
   myapp1
   myapp2
   myapp3
   myapp4
   global
```

Then I try to set the default for gemset `myapp1` to version `1.9.3-p194` and set it to default and that seems to work:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194@myapp1 --default
Using /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194 with gemset myapp1
```

But when I launch a new terminal window and do `rvm gemset list`, I end up back at square 1 - using a different versino of ruby - i.e. `1.9.3-p392` instead of `-p194`.

```
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p392 (found in /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392)
   (default)
=> myapp
   boso
   global
```

Does this happen because I don't close my previous terminal window before opening the new one? Do I have to force RVM to save it for all sessions or something?

What am I missing?

I also tried `rvm --default use 1.9.3.-p194@myapp1` and that gives me the same issue.

Comment: do `rvm use 1.9.3-p194@myapp1 --default` and then quit the terminal. open terminal back up and run `rvm list` and `rvm gemset list`. still an issue?

Comment: see the comments I left on your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you want a specific gemset and ruby version per project just manually create a `.rvmrc` file in your root project directly. In that file add:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p362@gemset-name --create
```

Or if you don't want to manually create it, you can have rvm do it for you. `cd` into the root directory of your project and create a `.rvmrc` file like this:

```
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@gemset-name --create --rvmrc
```

Make sure the `.rvmrc` file contains a line similar to this and in this format:

```
 environment_id="ruby-1.9.3-p392@gemset-name"
```

Update:

The convention used for setting the ruby version and a gemset  per project when using RVM is to use a `.ruby-version` file and a `.ruby-gemset` file in the project's root directory.

A `.ruby-version` file would look like this:

```
ruby-2.0.0-p598
```

A `.ruby-gemset` file would look like this:

```
my_gemset_name
```

Comment: I did this already. That's why there are all these gemsets when I do `rvm gemset list`. The issue is when I am launching a new Terminal window after having set the current directory to a new default in my existing Terminal window. That's where it doesn't work.

Comment: You were onto something though, I checked my `.rvmrc` file, and I found this variable set wrongly: `environment_id="ruby-1.9.3@myapp". So I changed that to `environment_id="ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp"` (with the specific `1.9.3` version) and it's working perfectly now. If you update your answer to reflect this, I will accept it.

Comment: I've actually manually created an `.rvmrc` file with the steps I gave above and it works fine. It works if you don't specify the patch level too. So let say you declare `1.9.3@gemset`, when you `cd` into that directory and you'll end up using `1.9.3-p194` since that's the newest ruby version you have. I would say the solution was probably fixing a corrupt rvmrc file.

Comment: Perhaps the way an .rvmrc file is created with RVM makes it so that it needs a patch declared? I wouldn't have thought it worked like that. Hmmmm

Comment: I think you may be right about when using `1.9.3@gemset` it uses the newest one. I believe `-p392` was the newest one, in my case. So it was always defaulting to the newest one.